# Logistic vs linear regression difference

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics

Can someone please differentiate logistic regression vs linear regression? I know that logistic regression is discrete (1, 0) and Linear regression is continuous. Could you provide two examples that set the two apart? Im just really confused on when to use which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered the question by yourself: linear regression is used for predicting continuous variables and logistic regression is used to predict binary variables. Here are some examples:

- Predict the price for a house in US dollar (a positive number): linear regression
- Predict the if certain person can afford certain home (can or cannot afford): logistic regression
- Predict a person's height in cm: linear regression
- Predict if a person has growth disorder (has disease or not): logistic regression
- Predict how much a person will spend per month: linear regression
- Predict if there are fraud transactions in a month (has fraud or no fraud): logistic regression

You can come up with more examples by yourself